# DAX - Measure Works when used against the required dimension but not alone in a card visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a requirement like this :-

```
Role_Skills = 
CONCATENATEX (
    FILTER (Jobs, Jobs[Role] = SELECTEDVALUE(Jobs[Role])),
    Jobs[Skills],
    ","
)
```

This Measure works when I put it on table against the Role.

But, it doesn't work alone in a Card Visual.

What changes do I need to make in it to make it work on a card visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECTEDVALUE` function will return a blank if it sees more than one value. Take out the `FILTER` function if you want it to work for all selected roles.

```
Role_Skills = CONCATENATEX ( Jobs, Jobs[Skills], "," )
```

Comment: ah thanks. Silly thing, didn't think about the functionality of SELECTEDVALUE and overthought the problem.